# Way to Rename all Functions/Methods to Random Names in Visual Studio Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, obfuscation

I need to create a macro to go through my 100000 line project and rename each function to random strings.

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Why not use something like Dotfuscator Community Edition?

Comment: Yes, plenty of people have.. Unfortunately, all of them sell the solution and because it is such a PITA to create it yourself it's generally much cheaper to just buy one.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a tool designed for this instead. For example, [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview).

Answer (score 1):

This is called an obfuscation of the code. In order to do this in .NET, you have to use [Dotfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator). Visual Studio installation is bundled with [Dotfuscator Community Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227240%28VS.80%29.aspx) (optional component).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest that you use a obfuscator such as dotfuscator, It will do what you want and will protect you're program further than just randomizing your function names...  Dotfuscator Community Edition is included with VS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to do this yourself, use an obfuscator such as the ones named above or [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm)